# Azure logic app: Copy FTP file is not copying entire file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created a Logic App that moves a file from one folder on my FTP server to another folder on the same FTP server. I made a loop that goes over every image in a folder and then copies it to another folder. For some reason the images copied are "white" and don't show the image.
(damaged and normal file added [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjgBKxqNsXTY4GNfxa5ye6D-NhF6?e=Rbqw3d))
What am I doing wrong?

Loop over every image in the folder:
[image: Fore-eaching over the images]

Copy the image to another folder:
[image: Copying the image]

Raw inputs

```
{
    "method": "post",
    "queries": {
        "destination": "/content/random/000test.jpg",
        "overwrite": "True",
        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": "True",
        "source": "/unreleased/random/000test.jpg"
    },
    "headers": {
        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": "True"
    },
    "path": "/datasets/default/copyFile",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/ftp-1"
        }
    }
}
```

Raw output

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "x-ms-request-id": "1db87e2f-9f4d-46d0-8ee3-8d586c155bba",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=b...caa0a07ccf2fa08b02852;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=ftp-ncus.azconn-ncus.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=b206...2;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=ftp-ncus.azconn-ncus.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
        "Date": "Tue, 22 Feb 2022 14:43:35 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1",
        "Content-Length": "350"
    },
    "body": {
        "Id": "L2NvbnRlbnQvcmFuZG9tLzAwMHRlc3QuanBn",
        "Name": "000test.jpg",
        "DisplayName": "000test.jpg",
        "Path": "/content/random/000test.jpg",
        "LastModified": "2022-02-22T14:43:35Z",
        "Size": 118764,
        "MediaType": "image/jpeg",
        "IsFolder": false,
        "ETag": "\"MDIvMjIvMjAyMiAxNDo0MzozNXwxMTg3NjQ=\"",
        "FileLocator": "L2NvbnRlbnQvcmFuZG9tLzAwMHRlc3QuanBn",
        "LastModifiedBy": null
    }
}
```

Here's the full code to my logic app:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each_3": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Copy_file": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "headers": {
                                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp_1']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/datasets/default/copyFile",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "destination": "/content/random/@{items('For_each_3')?['DisplayName']}",
                                        "overwrite": true,
                                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true,
                                        "source": "@items('For_each_3')?['Path']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "operationOptions": "DisableAsyncPattern",
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "Delay": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "interval": {
                                        "count": 10,
                                        "unit": "Second"
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Copy_file": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "Wait"
                            },
                            "Delete_file": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "headers": {
                                        "SkipDeleteIfFileNotFoundOnServer": false
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp_1']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "delete",
                                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_3')?['Path']))}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Increment_variable": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "Increment_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Amount",
                                    "value": 1
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Delay": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "IncrementVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "less": [
                                        "@variables('Amount')",
                                        10
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('List_files_in_folder')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "List_files_in_folder": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Amount",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "List_files_in_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/folders/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('L3VucmVsZWFzZWQvcmFuZG9t'))}"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "L3VucmVsZWFzZWQvcmFuZG9t": "/unreleased/random"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Friday"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Friday"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "ftp_1": {
                    "connectionId": "redacted../providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/ftp-1",
                    "connectionName": "ftp-1",
                    "id": "redacted"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the copied files the same size as the originals? Is the content-type of the copied files set correctly? If you open the copied files in a (binary) editor, do they contain data? Have you debugged the Logic App? What happens if you download the file? As you can see there are quite a few questions that need to be answered to provide us with enough information to help you.

Comment: Nope, when I download the file it is "damaged" as well according to win explorer. What do you mean by setting the content type? I'm using the default-built in copy task. What other things do I need to do before a copy works?

Comment: @rickvdbosch I added both of the files to the post

Comment: @rickvdbosch I provided all the info you asked. You need anything else?